# Rotate square imageView in ScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, rotation

I have a gallery of UIImageViews (that are SQUARE) declared as subviews of UIScrollView:

```
int size = self.view.frame.size.width/number;
int maxSize = [list count]; //amount of images to show in this view
imageViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0,j=1,k=0; i<maxSize; i++, j++){
   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[list objectAtIndex:i]];
   if (i % number == 0)
   {
      j = 1;
      k++;
   }
imageView.frame = CGRectMake((size*(j-1)), (size*(k-1)), size, size);
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[imageView setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[imageScrollView addSubview:imageView];
imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(size*number, size*(maxSize/number));
[imageScrollView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
```

In portrait mode everything is ok. However in landscape i want my images to become bigger both in axe X and Y. With pasted code my images get larger frame only in width, so they are wide and short. I want them to keep their ratio, so still to be square. Any idea..?

BTW: I tried to setAutoresizingMask to flexible height,top and bottom, but it makes my UIImages even shorter (i dont know why).

Comment: the question is, where you get sizeX from? an what is in number?

Comment: @Seega Sorry, sizeX == size, i changed it when copy-paste to stack overflow, didn't notice the one left. Corrected in my post already. Number is number of columns in gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote that the images should increase in size in landscape view, so where are you adjusting the UIImageViews frames? (And if they are getting smaller, then you have a bug in that missing piece of code.)

And @gamozzii is correct, you want the autoresizing on the imageviews to be:

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Comment: I just don't do it.. Hoped it can be done automatically ;) So i have to make array of images and resize each frame after rotation?

Comment: If so, then i want my scrollView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth; too..? Atm i have it set to flexible all dimensions (top,bottom,right,left,width,height) (to remind: i have imageViews inside scrollView)

Comment: Your scrollview can autoresize it's frame (height and width) - but when the frame changes, i think you'll still have to manually layout the children views.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want your margins to be flexible, leave them fixed, you only want the internal height/width to be flexible.  So try setting only the following two:

```
[imageView setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

Comment: In this case, when i rotate to landscape, all images are becoming smaller and smaller until they completely disappear...